# Can a malicious user submit data if there is no form?

Tags: html, forms

In my site, users can only modify their personal information only once a day. Script-side, I determine if they are allowed to (i.e. check with the database if it's been 24 hours since the last modification) and whether or not to display the form.

My question is, could a malicious user manage to submit information if there's no form? In other words, if there is no [`FORM element`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3) no data should be submitted by the user's browser, right?

What I'm afraid of is that if someone manages to send the data, the script would still process it and change the personal information **when it shouldn't**.

Comment: I can create a form and submit point it to whatever page I want.. And even a dummy user with no malice intentions can do the same, by viewing a cached copy of your page.

Comment: What is "script-side"? Do you mean client-side or server-side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course - this would be a kind of replay attack. So long as your resource endpoint will handle a malicious POST request, regardless of the content of the preceding GET then you're vulnerable.

Remember: **never trust the client**. Provided that you do authentication **and** authorization checks before handling a POST request then you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a malicious user can still send data even without the form, if he knows the url of the page which accepts the data and their corresponding attributes it expects. He can then easily create a form with that info and submit the data.

So you basically need to validate the data at the server-side.

Answer (score 1):

### YES

For example someone could use curl.

```
 curl -d profile=value http://www.yoursite.com/profile
```

You could prevent such attacks with a CSRF token you send along with your form.
See this article for more background http://shiflett.org/articles/cross-site-request-forgeries.